# oracle query consuming more Temp space

Tags: database, oracle11g

I have the following query which fails with error "ORA-01652
unable to extend the temp segment" when I try to run. (server-1)

I  tried the same query on a different server with more load and the query runs fine and returns the result set.(server-2)

Both the databases are 11.2.0.2.

The table space allocated for TEMP in both the servers is 1.6GB
I tried increasing the table space for TEMP in server-1 up to 5 GB and still the issue exists in server-1

The following is the Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    NC.CONNECTIONID C1, 
    NC.CONNECTIONNAME, 
    VCG.CONNECTIONNAME, 
    NC.CONNECTIONRATE, 
    NC.CONNECTIONSHAPE, 
    CASE WHEN SYSPARAMS.VALUE = 'COMBINED_ONLY' THEN DECODE(SO.ORDERTYPE, 8, NC.CONNECTIONSTATE,DECODE (SO.ORDERSTATE,'2', '9', NC.CONNECTIONSTATE)) ELSE NC.CONNECTIONSTATE END CONNECTIONSTATE, 
    NC.CONNECTIONDIRECTION, 
    NC.CONNECTIONCATEGORY, 
    NC.DISCREPANCY, 
    .
    .
    .
    NC.TANDEMASSOCIATIONTAG, 
    NC.CUSTOMERNAME, 
    TO_CHAR(CAST(SECONDS_TO_DATE(SO.INEFFECTDATE) AS TIMESTAMP), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.SS') || '+0000' INEFFECTDATE, NVL (NCG.NCGROUPNAME,'') BUNDLEAGGREGATENAME, 
    NVL (NCG.NCGROUPTYPE,'') NCGROUPTYPE, 
    NVL (BDCST.NCGROUPNAME, '') BROADCASTGROUPNAME

FROM    SYSPARAMS, 
        SERVICEORDER SO, 
        NETWORKCONNECTION NC, 
        NETWORKCONNECTION VCG, 
        OMSCONNENDTPS NCC, 
        ( SELECT UNIQUE NX.HANDLE FROM NODE NX, TOPLEVELSUBNETWORK TLS, MANAGER WHERE TLS.NAME LIKE 'abcd' AND (NX.TOPMLSHANDLE = TLS.HANDLE OR NX.MLSHANDLE = TLS.HANDLE OR MANAGER.HANDLE = TLS.HANDLE) ) NES, 
        NCGROUP NCG, 
        NCGROUP BDCST 

WHERE 

    NC.CONNECTIONRATE IN (1165,1155,1125,1120,1115,1110,1105)  
    AND SYSPARAMS.NAME = 'NBI_TMF_SNC_OPS'  
    AND NC.CONNECTIONSTATE IN (2,7,8,9) 
    AND SO.ORDERTYPE != 3  
    AND NCC.CONNECTIONID=NC.CONNECTIONID 
    AND SO.CONNECTIONID=NC.CONNECTIONID  
    AND NC.CONNECTIONSHAPE IN (1, 2, 8, 10, 13, 14)  

    AND NCC.SRCNEID=NES.HANDLE 
    AND ( NCC.SINKTPID != NCC.SRCTPID  OR (NCC.SINKTPID = NCC.SRCTPID  AND NC.CONNECTIONSHAPE = 10 ))  
    AND NC.NCGROUPID = NCG.NCGROUPID (+) 
    AND NC.BDCSTGROUPID = BDCST.NCGROUPID (+) 
    AND NC.NCGROUPID = VCG.SERVERGROUPID (+) 

    ORDER BY C1,OMSCONNENDTPSID
```

I tried to compare the execution plans for the query on both machines

Execution Plan on server-1

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                     | Name                         | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                              |                              |   128K|    35M|       | 25930   (3)| 00:05:12 |
|   1 |  SORT UNIQUE                                  |                              |   128K|    35M|    37M| 17886   (4)| 00:03:35 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS OUTER                          |                              |   128K|    35M|       |  9842   (6)| 00:01:59 |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                      |                              |   128K|    33M|       |  9841   (6)| 00:01:59 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                         | NCGROUP                      | 31020 |   514K|       |    28  (11)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |     HASH JOIN                                 |                              |   128K|    31M|       |  9805   (6)| 00:01:58 |
|   6 |      VIEW                                     |                              | 20614 |   100K|       |   827  (72)| 00:00:10 |
|   7 |       HASH UNIQUE                             |                              | 20614 |   583K|  5672K|   827  (11)| 00:00:10 |
|   8 |        CONCATENATION                          |                              |       |       |       |            |          |
|   9 |         MERGE JOIN                            |                              |   144K|  4086K|       |   151  (12)| 00:00:02 |
|  10 |          MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN                 |                              | 20614 |   322K|       |   105   (6)| 00:00:02 |
|  11 |           INDEX FULL SCAN                     | MANAGER_PKEY                 |     1 |     2 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  12 |           BUFFER SORT                         |                              | 20614 |   281K|       |   104   (6)| 00:00:02 |
|  13 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | NODE                         | 20614 |   281K|       |   104   (6)| 00:00:02 |
|* 14 |          SORT JOIN                            |                              |     7 |    91 |       |    40  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|  15 |           VIEW                                | TOPLEVELSUBNETWORK           |     7 |    91 |       |    39  (13)| 00:00:01 |
|  16 |            SORT UNIQUE                        |                              |     7 |  1507 |       |    39  (83)| 00:00:01 |
|  17 |             UNION-ALL                         |                              |       |       |       |            |          |
|  18 |              NESTED LOOPS OUTER               |                              |     1 |   114 |       |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  19 |               NESTED LOOPS                    |                              |     1 |    95 |       |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  20 |                NESTED LOOPS                   |                              |     1 |    51 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 21 |                 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | SYSPARAMS                    |     1 |    27 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 22 |                  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | SYSPARAMS_PKEY               |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 23 |                 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | NODE                         |     1 |    24 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |

| 126 |                  UNION-ALL                    |                              |       |       |       |            |          |
|*127 |                   HASH JOIN                   |                              |     2 |   126 |       |     9  (12)| 00:00:01 |
| 128 |                    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| NCG                          |     1 |    40 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*129 |                     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | NCG_NAME                     |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 130 |                    TABLE ACCESS FULL          | NETWORKCONTROLLER            |    76 |  1748 |       |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*131 |                   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | NODE                         |     1 |    26 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*132 |                    INDEX RANGE SCAN           | NODE_NAME                    |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*133 |           INDEX RANGE SCAN                    | NODE_TPLVLSBNTWKHDL          |  1085 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*134 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID          | NODE                         |    35 |   490 |       |    30   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*135 |      HASH JOIN                                |                              |   128K|    30M|    15M|  9535   (6)| 00:01:55 |
|*136 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL                       | SERVICEORDER                 |   325K|    12M|       |  1266   (8)| 00:00:16 |
|*137 |       HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                   |                              |   121K|    24M|    11M|  6153   (6)| 00:01:14 |
| 138 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL                      | NETWORKCONNECTION            |   255K|  8981K|       |  1310   (8)| 00:00:16 |
|*139 |        HASH JOIN                              |                              |   121K|    20M|  9984K|  3146   (8)| 00:00:38 |
| 140 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | OMSCONNENDTPS                |   255K|  6985K|       |   322  (10)| 00:00:04 |
| 141 |         NESTED LOOPS                          |                              |   120K|    17M|       |  1387  (13)| 00:00:17 |
| 142 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID          | SYSPARAMS                    |     1 |    27 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*143 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                   | SYSPARAMS_PKEY               |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*144 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL                    | NETWORKCONNECTION            |   120K|    14M|       |  1386  (13)| 00:00:17 |
| 145 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                | NCGROUP                      |     1 |    14 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*146 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                         | NCGROUP_PKEY                 |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Execution plan on server-2

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                   | Name                         | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                            |                              |   290K|    76M|       | 51114   (3)| 00:10:14 |
|   1 |  SORT UNIQUE                                |                              |   290K|    76M|    81M| 33578   (4)| 00:06:43 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN                                 |                              |   290K|    76M|       | 16041   (6)| 00:03:13 |
|   3 |    VIEW                                     |                              | 24239 |   118K|       |   370  (20)| 00:00:05 |
|   4 |     HASH UNIQUE                             |                              | 24239 |   710K|       |   370  (20)| 00:00:05 |
|   5 |      CONCATENATION                          |                              |       |       |       |            |          |
|   6 |       MERGE JOIN                            |                              |   121K|  3550K|       |   210  (10)| 00:00:03 |
|   7 |        MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN                 |                              | 24239 |   402K|       |   156   (6)| 00:00:02 |
|   8 |         INDEX FULL SCAN                     | MANAGER_PKEY                 |     1 |     2 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |         BUFFER SORT                         |                              | 24239 |   355K|       |   155   (6)| 00:00:02 |
|  10 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | NODE                         | 24239 |   355K|       |   155   (6)| 00:00:02 |
|* 11 |        SORT JOIN                            |                              |     5 |    65 |       |    49  (13)| 00:00:01 |
|  12 |         VIEW                                | TOPLEVELSUBNETWORK           |     5 |    65 |       |    48  (11)| 00:00:01 |
|  13 |          SORT UNIQUE                        |                              |     5 |  1046 |       |    48  (67)| 00:00:01 |
|  14 |           UNION-ALL                         |                              |       |       |       |            |          |
|  15 |            NESTED LOOPS OUTER               |                              |     1 |   117 |       |    16   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  16 |             NESTED LOOPS                    |                              |     1 |    97 |       |    15   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  17 |              NESTED LOOPS                   |                              |     1 |    53 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 18 |               TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | SYSPARAMS                    |     1 |    27 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 19 |                INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | SYSPARAMS_PKEY               |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 20 |               TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | NODE                         |     1 |    26 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 21 |                INDEX RANGE SCAN             | NODE_NAME                    |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  22 |              TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | MULTILAYERSUBNETWORK         |     1 |    44 |       |    13   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 23 |               INDEX SKIP SCAN               | MULTILAYERSUBNETWORK_NCHDLNM |     1 |       |       |    12   (0)| 00:00:01 |

|*126 |                   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | NCG_NAME                     |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 127 |                  TABLE ACCESS FULL          | NETWORKCONTROLLER            |   127 |  3048 |       |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*128 |                 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | NODE                         |     1 |    28 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*129 |                  INDEX RANGE SCAN           | NODE_NAME                    |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*130 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN                    | NODE_TPLVLSBNTWKHDL          |   673 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*131 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID          | NODE                         |    35 |   525 |       |    18   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 132 |    NESTED LOOPS OUTER                       |                              |   290K|    75M|       | 15699   (5)| 00:03:09 |
|*133 |     HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                   |                              |   290K|    71M|       | 15688   (5)| 00:03:09 |
| 134 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                      | NCGROUP                      | 17940 |   315K|       |    21  (10)| 00:00:01 |
|*135 |      HASH JOIN                              |                              |   290K|    66M|    20M| 15652   (5)| 00:03:08 |
|*136 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | SERVICEORDER                 |   427K|    15M|       |  1791   (8)| 00:00:22 |
|*137 |       HASH JOIN                             |                              |   284K|    54M|    14M|  9901   (6)| 00:01:59 |
| 138 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL                    | OMSCONNENDTPS                |   354K|    10M|       |   440  (10)| 00:00:06 |
|*139 |        HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                |                              |   281K|    45M|    14M|  6272   (7)| 00:01:16 |
| 140 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL                   | NETWORKCONNECTION            |   348K|    10M|       |  1689   (8)| 00:00:21 |
| 141 |         NESTED LOOPS                        |                              |   281K|    37M|       |  1799  (14)| 00:00:22 |
| 142 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID        | SYSPARAMS                    |     1 |    27 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*143 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                 | SYSPARAMS_PKEY               |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*144 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | NETWORKCONNECTION            |   281K|    29M|       |  1798  (14)| 00:00:22 |
| 145 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID             | NCGROUP                      |     1 |    15 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*146 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                      | NCGROUP_PKEY                 |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Intrestingly server-1(with issue) shows low TEMP space needed in execution plan.
when compared to server-2(no issue with more load)

I have also compared the following parameters on both the machines and they remain the same:
optimizer_mode,optimizer_index_cost_adj,optimizer_index_caching,db_file_multiblock_read_count,parallel_automatic_tuning,hash_area_size,sort_area_size

Can some one help me on points that need to be compared on both the machines which could influence the execution plan and usage of TEMP space.

Answer (score 0):

The ancient join syntax you are using obfuscates how you link the tables. Use explicit joins to see what is happening. Here is your derived table NES re-written:

```
select unique 
  nx.handle 
from node nx
cross join manager 
join toplevelsubnetwork tls 
  on  tls.name like 'abcd' 
  and tls.handle in (nx.topmlshandle, nx.mlshandle, manager.handle)
```

This creates a big intermediate result. And as you cross join node with every manager, it suffices for the tls.handle to match any manager.handle and you get all nx.handle that exist. Think this subquery over and your problem should be solved.

(And when you are at it, replace the implicit joins in your main query, too, with explicit joins. It's a nuisance to have to muddle through the whole where clause only to see how you join the tables.)

Comment: Thanks for input.
I tried the explicit join you mentioned. An the result looks the same.
I will also try to modify the entire query with explicit joins and check.
Since this query is working fine on database with higher load..Any hints wrt oracle parameters that can be tuned.

Comment: An also the entries in node=201614